# Conditional UI elements in a RecyclerView adapter based on position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am building a leaderboard app and would like to show trophy icons for first, second and third place.

I would like to be able to do this in a RecyclerView without having to have multiple adapters.

Comment: You just need to learn how to create a recyclerview. Go ahead and research how to do the basic and go on from there. There is a Guide in the Android Developer site here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview. Go check it out and go back here if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your adapters ViewHolder you will have a `position`. In Java I believe you access this using `viewHolder.getPosition()`

Once you have a `position` you can create a statement as follows

```
if (position == 0) { //ADD FIRST PLACE ICON } 
else if (position == 1) { //ADD SECOND PLACE ICON }
else if (position == 2) { //ADD THIRD PLACE ICON } 
else { //HIDE TROPHY ICON }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onBindViewHolder() method in recyclerview adapter use the position to show/hide item views:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        // Show 1st place trophy

    } else if (position == 1) {
        // Show 2nd place trophy

    } else if (position == 2) {
        // Show 3rd place trophy

    } else {
        // Hide trophy
    }
}
```